# Blackberry with mjsip

Tags: blackberry, sip

i want to create VOIP based app for blackberry. after research, i found that mjsip is used for blackberry voip. but i don't how to integrate mjsip with BB.

any help?

thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is a SIP library. There is also a ME version of mjsip so I suppose that you could port it for blackberry without too much effort.

Creating VOIP applications for blackberry is a really complicated task and I don't advice you to do it unless you are willing to spend many many hours in research. There is a reason why there are so few voip apps for blackberry.
RIM does not support JSR 180 - i.e. there is no build in support for session initiation and management. So you have to use third party libraries like mjsipME or sip-4-me to manage your sessions.

If you don't know what SIP here is an article:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol

Comment: i have create BB project and import MJSIP, it compile fine but give nullpointer exception at runtime,do you know solution or how to use MJSIP?

Comment: Are you new to software development or java/javaME development? Debug your code, log some info and check where and why the error occurs. Note that mjsipME is java ME based and probably requires some action from your side in order to port it to blackberry. Don't think that if it compiles it will run on bb! Usually these libraries require some porting so you will have to do it yourself.